# Ubuntu OpenStack Autopilot Juju Bootstrap no progress

Tags: maas, cloud, openstack-autopilot, conjure-up

I'm trying to deploy an Ubuntu Openstack Setup with Autopilot.
Following the official instructions (`https://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/autopilot`), I've setup a MAAS Server and made PXE Booting working and can deploy a vanilla ubuntu in a VM.

But following the tutorial, in step six after commissioning a VM dedicated for JuJu I should deploy it with conjure up from the terminal with this command `conjure-up --bootstrap-to <hostname>`. But this process "fails" sort of.

The conjure-up command does nothing on the MAAS Server apart from running apt update and installing curl and a few other tools, while the Juju Controller VM sits around idleing

[MAAS Controller Screenshot](https://gyazo.com/b55ab5dd51f80154d1a74b5d55419d7e)

[JUJU VM Screenshot](https://gyazo.com/ee4e0d030c12116901e8124b289f357d)

I'd appreciate any help or suggestions regarding my errors. Thank You!

Comment: Does MAAS power on/off those vm's without you needing to do it manually?

Comment: No, it's manual. The developer informed me, that the VM needs to be started automatically, otherwise timing might be off and error occur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VM needs to be powered on automatically be MAAS